# Change confusing message when vote is locked in

Tags: feature-request, voting, stack-exchange

When I try and undo a vote on a question after the grace period has expired, the message given is:

> You last voted on this answer 47 mins ago. 
>   **Your vote is now locked in** unless this answer is edited
>   <sub>(*emphasis mine*)</sub>

The use of the phrase "**Your vote is now locked in**" implies I just did something that affects the status of my vote. But this is not true: my vote has been locked in from the moment the grace period expired.

When I first started to use the site, I used to think I had double-clicked by accident and had inadvertently locked in an up-vote that I tried to undo.

Some suggested new wording:

> Votes lock after 5 minutes; you voted 20 minutes ago. Your vote cannot be changed unless this answer is edited.

This also has the benefit of alerting users to the grace period duration.

Comment: Replacing "is now locked in" with "has now been locked in" may be sufficient to remove the implication that the user is the one who did the locking.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I don't think that fixes it. I think the "now" is the part that must go.

Comment: @Duncan, I see. Well, replacing "now" with "since" would make it a bit less misleading, but the language you suggest in your post would be much more informative.